# Call contract function with address and abi to return value to frontend

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, web3js, frontend

I've deployed the following contract to Ethereum testnet.

```
contract demo {
  string public name = "someString"; 

  function returnValue() constant returns (string){ 
      return name;    
  }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the contract's string and this won't work

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAddress, abi); //contractAddress+abi known
console.log(contract.returnValue);
```

returns `undefined`

If I use this code:

```
var asdf = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
alert(asdf.returnValue);
```

I get `function(){[native code]}
How can i get the string "name" from my solidity contract to my javascript? Thank you

Comment: just read the doc https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods

Comment: That's where I got my code from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray).at(contractAddress);
contract.returnValue.call().then(function(v) {
    var strName= v.toString();
    console.log("Name: "+ strName);   
});
```

This is how I do using truffle:

```
import demo_artifacts from './../../build/contracts/demo.json';  
var Demo = contract(demo_artifacts);

window.getValue=function(){  
    Demo.deployed().then(function(contractInstance) {  
        contractInstance.returnValue.call().then(function(v) {  
            var strName= v.toString();  
            console.log("Name: "+ strName);
        });    
    });  
}    
window.getValue();
```

Try this one:

```
var abiDef = "(provide the abi)";   
var contractAddress = "(provide the contract address)";  
var objWeb3 = new Web3(new
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));   
var democontract = objWeb3.eth.contract( JSON.parse(abiDef)).at(contractAddress);  
var callData=democontract.returnValue.call();
console.log(callData); // Printed: BigNumber {s: 1, e: 3, c: Array[1]}  
console.log(callData.c[0]); // Printed: the value in my case 1000
```

Comment: this is what I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

Comment: Try updated code

Comment: I am not using truffle. I use the web3 Javascript API, that probably why the call() function won't work

Comment: Added another version try that